# Use proxy for transmissions on certain url?

Tags: 14.04, server, proxy

for some reason my server isp is blocking certain urls on port 443 , is there any way so i can pass just those urls transmissions through a proxy ?

`api.example.com:443` and `server.example.com:443`

**if i use** :

```
openssl s_client -connect api.example.com:443
```

**the result is** : `connect: Connection timed out`

But if i connect with through a proxy on my server , i can connect , but i don't want to take whole eth into proxy i just want to somehow create a rule or something that when system try to connect those urls , they go through proxy !

any tips or suggestions ? i really appreciate that , thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing your dns settings ? Generally helps. Let me know if you want me to post a link or an answer on how to do that

Answer (score 3):

I see several options.

1. Set up your program to use the proxy.  The details on how to do that differ from program to program.  Unfortunately, you don't mention which program you want to use the proxy.
2. Set the `https_proxy` environment variable for your program, hoping that it will respect it.
3. Transparently force it to use your proxy using either [httppc](http://httppc.sourceforge.net/), [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/),  or [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/), depending on the type of proxy you want to use. Unfortunately, you don't mention which type of proxy you envision to use.
4. Transparently force your application to use your proxy using iptables. There is description of how to achieve that on [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html). There is also a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10595575/2015768). You may find [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/transparent/linux.html) an easier to maintain setup.

Comment: I would have set #2 to #4 as it contains the word "hope", but didn't even think of #1!  Good answer! (and an upvote)

Comment: i don't have access to program sourcecode , i am using serverpilot , i want this : api.serverpilot.io & manage.serverpilot.io go through proxy !